# Get item from Guzzle stream

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I currently have the following code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

// Get current round ID
$roundRequest = $client->get('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/rounds/2/current');
$roundResponse = $roundRequest->getBody();
```

Which returns the following Guzzle stream:

```
{"api":{"results":1,"fixtures":["Regular_Season_-_38"]}}
```

What's the best way to change this to a format which I can easily grab the value of the 'fixtures' subarray (which will only ever include a single value) from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$response = json_decode($roundRequest->getBody()->getContents());
```

Comment: Worth pointing out if you want to use `$response` as an array then use `$response = json_decode($roundRequest->getBody()->getContents(), true);`